# Json no se lee en el Servidor web

Tags: php, curl

Tengo la respuesta de un web service de la cual llega en formato json por medio de cURL y necesito algunos valores así:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $co_web_service,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($document),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $co_token_enterprise
  ),
));

$response_doc = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$json_document_object = json_decode($response_doc);
```

Así capturo los valores en local host y llegan bien:

```
$doc_ZipKey = $json_document_object->Response->Envelope->Body->SendTestSetAsyncResponse->SendTestSetAsyncResult->ZipKey;

$doc_StatusCode = $json_document_object->Response->Envelope->Body->GetStatusZipResponse->GetStatusZipResult->OtroResponse->StatusCode;

$doc_StatusDescription = $json_document_object->Response->Envelope->Body->GetStatusZipResponse->GetStatusZipResult->OtroResponse->StatusDescription;
```

De la misma manera lo hago en el servidor web, pero allí los valores llegan vacíos...

El cURL esta habilitado en el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Es necesario validar `$json_document_object` después de decodificar el json para ver si hay errores

```
if (isset($json_document_object->errors)){
  foreach ($json_document_object->errors as $indexError => $messagesError) {
    foreach ($messagesError as $err => $mess){
      $response_final['message'] .= $mess . "<br>";
    }
  }
  $response_final['message'] .= "<strong>Corrija los Problemas e Intente mas Tarde!</strong>";
  echo json_encode($response_final);
  exit;
}
```